# AngularJS access object field in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, factory

So i got this AngularJS controller where i need to use 2 different services `Project` and `Subproject`. One is linked to the other by `project_id` field. The code is as follows:

```
bonsControllers.controller('SubprojetDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'Project', 'Subproject',
  function($scope, $routeParams, Project, Subproject) {

    $scope.subproject = Subproject.queryFalse({projectId: $routeParams.id});     

    $scope.project = Project.queryFalse({projectId: $scope.subproject.project_id});
}]);
```

The problem is when I use in `$scope.project` or even using it on console.log, the value for `$scope.subproject.project_id` is undefined.

The services.js code is :

```
    var bonsServices = angular.module('bonsServices', ['ngResource']);

    bonsServices.factory('Project', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        return $resource(URL_API + '/projects/:projectId', {}, {
            queryTrue: {method: 'GET', params: {projectId: ''}, isArray: true},         
            queryFalse: {method: 'GET', params: {projectId: ''}, isArray: false},           
            save: {method: 'POST', headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, isArray: false},
            'delete': {method: 'DELETE', params: {projectId: ''}, isArray: false},
            update: {method: 'PUT', params: {projectId: ''}, headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, isArray: false}
        });
    }]);


bonsServices.factory('Subproject', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        return $resource(URL_API + '/subprojects/:projectId', {}, {         
            queryFalse: {method: 'GET', params: {projectId: ''}, isArray: false}
        });
    }]);
```

And the template code is :

```
<div >
    <span>Client :</span> {{project.client.name}} <br />
    <span>Projet :</span> {{project.name}} <br />
    <span>Sous Projet :</span> {{'Saison ' + subproject.saison}} <br />
    <span>Type :</span> {{project.type}} {{subproject.project_id}}<br />
    <span>Nature :</span> {{subproject.nature}} <br />
</div>
```

In Firebug I can see clearly all $scope.subproject's elements, including project_id

I would very much apreciate if you guys can give me a hint on this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide a plunkr or jsfiddle?

Comment: I can provide the services code and also the templates code if you want

Comment: yes please, provide the services code

Comment: Sanity check:  In the question you're spelling it as both projet and project; are you making the same error on the rest of your code?

Comment: No Dan ... I tried to sanitise the code before posting it here but it seems i havent done a good job
The app works quite ok except that line of code

Comment: Ok I've corrected the exemple codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code worked for me and it follows Konstantin's answer :

```
bonsControllers.controller('SubprojetDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'Project', 'Subproject',
  function($scope, $routeParams, Project, Subproject) 
  {

    var project;
    $scope.subproject = Subproject.queryFalse({projectId: $routeParams.id});
    $scope.subproject.$promise.then(function(subproject){
        project = Project.queryFalse({projectId: subproject.project_id});  
        $scope.project = project;
    }); 
  }
]);
```

As you might see $promise.then does the trick for me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sure, because the Subproject service has an async query there. It will return a promise, when it's done.

```
bonsControllers.controller('SubprojetDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'Project', 'Subproject',
  function($scope, $routeParams, Project, Subproject) {

    Subproject.queryFalse({projectId: $routeParams.id})
    .then(function(subproject){
      $scope.subproject = subproject;
      return Project.queryFalse({projectId: $scope.subproject.project_id});
    }).then(function(project){
      $scope.project = project;
    });           
}]);
```

And the reason why firebug logs all elements, because it will log a reference to the objects, the console log then refreshes the object data, when the query is done. So for some milliseconds the data is undefined and will be populated when query is done.

To be sure, that the console.logged data is there, just write `$scope.subproject.project_id`

Comment: Unfortunatelly Konstantin when I use your code i get this error : Error: Subproject.queryFalse(...).then is not a function

Its weird because the code you provided seems logic and in phase with the rest of the code.